# How to add custom fonts from google fonts in tailwindcss?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[image]I followed the instruction on YouTube, but I can't use the font family "nunito." I put the @import within the CSS file inside the "src" folder and run "npm run (script name)" into the terminal, but nothing works.

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        nunito: ["Nunito"], // ! find out why this fontFamily still not register to the styles.css inside the public -o output folder.
      },
      colors: {
        // THIS IS THE ADDITIONAL COLOR STYLES
        primary: "#FF6363",
        secondary: {
          100: "#E2E2D5",
          100: "#888883",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Can you add here your CSS file? Where you importing the font face.

Comment: I will edit the code I will the code in my file sir.

Comment: added image of the src file Sir @Seno

Comment: Thanks, where do you declare the font family? Try adding `font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;` to the `body` tag in your CSS.

It will be like this:  `body { font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}`

Comment: Actually, that's the declaration in the tailwind config. I'm not using native css, it's tailwind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Based on their docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing) you might have been declare the key wrong, you missed the single quotes on Nunito key. It should be: `'nunito': ['Nunito']`.

Comment: Yes but when I'm saving it the ' ' automatically disappeared.

Comment: Interesting, do you have the eslint installed or other JS linting on?

Comment: Ohhh, I got it It's just my code formatter in VS code plug in. Thank you! it's working now.